# Use cases for HTML selects and Calendar for inputting dates to a form

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, seo

I've been wondering about the different use cases for inputting dates to an html form. Is there a particular case where, for example, using selects is more convenient than just popping up a calendar? Is there a case where the calendar is better? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think that a regular textbox with the expected format is often enough, you just need to validate so the user can't put crazy things. But, depends on what do you need, for mobiles the textbox is the best way. I recommend you to take a look of this: 
http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-users-fill-out-forms-faster-with-unified-text-fields/